# L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon critical error

Tags: ubuntu, vpn

I am currently trying to use **l2tp-ipsec-vpn** in my ubuntu machine.
I followed a guide from [tuxfamily](http://wiki.l2tpipsecvpn.tuxfamily.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Ubuntu) to install it.

Unfortanely, when I start the system, I got a window with the following error:

```
A critical error occurred:
L2tpIPsecVpnControlDaemon is not started
```

Any throughts how to fix it?